# Change the Key with CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I am using CryptoJS to encrypt and decrypt the text. Here, I am just taking the message and showing the both encryption and decryption messages.

I am using DES algorithm for encrypting and decrypting.

This is my HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="tripledes.js"></script>
    <script src="mode-ecb.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .maindiv {
            /* Just to center the form on the page */
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 400px;
            /* To see the outline of the form */
            padding: 1em;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            border-radius: 1em;
        }
         div + div {
                margin-top: 1em;
            }
        label {
            /* To make sure that all labels have the same size and are properly aligned */
            display: inline-block;
            width: 90px;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .button {
            /* To position the buttons to the same position of the text fields */
            padding-left: 90px; /* same size as the label elements */
        }

        button {
            /* This extra margin represent roughly the same space as the space
       between the labels and their text fields */
            margin-left: .5em;
        }
        input:focus, textarea:focus {
            /* To give a little highlight on active elements */
            border-color: #000;
        }
        input, textarea {
            /* To make sure that all text fields have the same font settings
       By default, textareas have a monospace font */
            font: 1em sans-serif;
            /* To give the same size to all text field */
            width: 300px;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            /* To harmonize the look & feel of text field border */
            border: 1px solid #999;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function viewvalue()
        {
            var message = document.getElementById("msg").value;
            var key = document.getElementById("key").value;
            var encrypted = encryptByDES(message, key);
            document.getElementById("enctext").textContent = encrypted;
            document.getElementById("dectxt").textContent = decryptByDES(encrypted, key);;


        }

        function encryptByDES(message, key) {

            var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);

            var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(message, keyHex, {
                mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
            });
            return encrypted.toString();
        }

        function decryptByDES(ciphertext, key) {
            var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);

            var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt({
                ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertext)
            }, keyHex, {
                mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
            });

            return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="maindiv">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Message:</label>
            <input type="text" id="msg" name="msg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="mail">Key:</label>
            <input type="text" id="key" name="key" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="msg">Encrypted Text:</label>
            <textarea id="enctext" name="enctxt"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="msg">Decrypted Text:</label>
            <textarea id="dectxt" name="dectxt"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <button onclick="viewvalue()">View</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my .js file

```
/*
CryptoJS v3.1.2
code.google.com/p/crypto-js
(c) 2009-2013 by Jeff Mott. All rights reserved.
code.google.com/p/crypto-js/wiki/License
*/
/**
 * Electronic Codebook block mode.
 */
CryptoJS.mode.ECB = (function () {
    var ECB = CryptoJS.lib.BlockCipherMode.extend();

    ECB.Encryptor = ECB.extend({
        processBlock: function (words, offset) {
            this._cipher.encryptBlock(words, offset);
        }
    });

    ECB.Decryptor = ECB.extend({
        processBlock: function (words, offset) {
            this._cipher.decryptBlock(words, offset);
        }
    });

    return ECB;
}());
```

Please anyone can tell me where and how to change the key.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? There is a line in the ````viewvalue()```` function that says ````var key = document.getElementById("key").value;```` so you change the key by changing what's written in the #key input field, or simply by calling ````encryptByDES()```` directly with your message and key.

Comment: It is for use when there is another key present for encryption and decryption...than I will use key otherwise if there is no key present use default key

Comment: @ShubhamVashishtha I don't understand what you're asking here. What's your key and why do you want to change it? What's the problem you're encountering? There is an input field which is supposed to hold the key.

Comment: **Don't use DES nowadays.** It only provides 56 bit of security. AES would be a much better, because it's more secure with the lowest key size of 128 bit. There is also a practical limit on the maximum ciphertext size with DES. See [Security comparsion of 3DES and AES](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/26179/45523).

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Actually, I want to change the key value which is used in this because I am decrypting data response and the guys have used this particular key. Also, I know we should not use it and least secure but it is not mine...I am just decrypting a text and studying the response

Comment: I'm still not clear on what the problem is. You can type into the `#key` input field and change it, can't you?

Comment: No I can't change I tried but when I entered the text in key it is not working at all

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs at https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/#Custom_Key_and_IV, you would need to define and supply both the initialisation vector (IV) and the key if you wish to provide a custom key:

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f'); 
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f'); 
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", key, { iv: iv });
```

Comment: var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f');  so here (000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f') is the key right? and instead I have to use mine

Comment: To use regular words instead of a hex string as above you'd instead use something like this:

`var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8); 
var key128Bits = CryptoJS.PBKDF2("Secret Passphrase", salt, { keySize: 128/32 }); 
var key256Bits = CryptoJS.PBKDF2("Secret Passphrase", salt, { keySize: 256/32 }); 
var key512Bits = CryptoJS.PBKDF2("Secret Passphrase", salt, { keySize: 512/32 }); 
var key512Bits1000Iterations = CryptoJS.PBKDF2("Secret Passphrase", salt, { keySize: 512/32, iterations: 1000 });`

See https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/#PBKDF2 for reference

Comment: sorry I am not understanding it properly...here "Secret Passphrase" is where you write your secret key text am I right?

Comment: Yes, Secret Passphrase would be your secret key text. As per the other comments, ensure you're not using DES, or ECB.

Comment: Can this "Secret Passphrase" be encrypted because the key I get is in encrypted form and how I don't how to get the text or hex from it. I used decrypto tool from Adbobe which we use to decrypt the response file but it is also throwing error that Invalid padding value expected[29] found [210]....